# Open source tool comparable to MATLAB Neural Network Tool Box?

Tags: python, machine-learning, languages, java

**Background**

I am a graduate student and a researcher. I do not like to rely on commercial products due to cost and also because I feel more comfortable in using and extending existing tools based on languages such as Java, Python, C#, and R.

Right now I want to establish a base line of classic neural networks before I extend my work into deep learning. I consider the following essential for my baseline: ANNs for ARMA such as: Simple recurrent networks (SRN), Elman-Jordan (RNN); Time Delay Neural Networks (TDNN); and Gamma Memories.

**Problem**

I need a single open source tool that can do Simple Recurrent Networks, Elman - Jordan, Time Delay Neural Networks, and Gamma Memories. This will allow me to establish my baseline and then extend my work into deep learning.

**Attempts**

Unfortunately, the only two tools I found so far are both commercial. One is MATLAB Neural Networks Toolbox and the other is a package called Neurosolutions. I found a very similar post [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5110/python-oss-alternatives-for-matlab-neural-network-toolbox-any-intercomparisons), but the original poster was too general and I didn't see any good answers for my issue. My needs are very specific to the above problem.

I deeply thank everyone for reading this question and appreciate your kind assistance.

Comment: There are a variety of free neural network packages that have been put together for the Julia programming language. Some are listed on their package site (http://pkg.julialang.org/), but you should google around for "unofficial" packages as well.

Comment: @TylerOlsen Thanks for the link. I didn't see anything specifically for the networks I am interested in yet on Julian (saw other ML packages like SVM, kNN, and etc), but that platform looks interesting nevertheless.

Comment: For machine learning there is [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html).

Comment: The Python options are listed at http://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/695

Answer (score 1):

Python in conjunction with Theano.

Many deep learning and neural network packages developed in Python are built on top of or are just higher level interfaces to Theano.

Check out http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/ for more information.

*Please note that I would have added this post as a comment, as opposed to an answer, but unfortunately I don't have enough rep points yet.*

Comment: It would be helpful if you can elaborate on your answer.

Comment: Okay, I did that just now. Sorry.

Comment: As far as I understand, Tensorflow library in Python is more popular than Theano now.

Comment: That is indeed correct.  There are a myriad of options for neural networks.  Some other popular ones are Torch, Caffe(2), and CNTK.